# javascript json object decode

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am new to JSON and AJAX and was hoping someone could help me out here.

Using an AJAX request to a PHP script, I get some data from SQL database -> encoded as JSON string and sent it back to the calling javascript.

This is the data i get back

```
Array[{"categoryName":"Apartments For Rent"},{"categoryName":"Apartments For Sale"},{"categoryName":"Room For Rent (Shared)"},{"categoryName":"Paying Guest"},{"categoryName":"Office\/Shop\/Commercial Space"},{"categoryName":"Land"},{"categoryName":"Parking Spots"},{"categoryName":"Other"}]
```

How can I get the individual 'CategoryName' values from this (in a while loop)?

EDIT : PHP CODE THAT SENDS THE JSON DATA

```
    $arr = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($temp,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $arr[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Thank you for the help
Ankit

Comment: That does not seem  to be valid JSON. Where does `Array` come from?

Comment: @Felix : Added the PHP code that produces the JSON string

Comment: It seems you are doing another `echo` somewhere or you just included `Array` by accident. Make sure it is not in the response.

Comment: @Felix. Thank you for pointing that out. I had missed out on an echo statement that was adding the 'Array' part. Fixing that solved it all. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the array and access individual elements by their index:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    alert(data[i].categoryName);
}
```

Comment: `data.length` returns `290`. So it seems the returned JSON object is being treated as a string.

Comment: @ankit, try parsing it then: `JSON.parse(data);` and operate on the result of this function. The `JSON.parse` method can be found in `json2.js`: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: Works like a charm now after removing the stray echo statment suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

Use eval() to decode it to a javascript object and then loop trough it, but you'll have to remove the "Array" at the start on the php side or using javascript.

```
var jsonStr = '[{"categoryName":"Apartments For Rent"},{"categoryName":"Apartments For Sale"}]';
jsonObj = eval("("+jsonStr+")");
for(var i in jsonObj){
  categoryName = jsonObj[i].categoryName;
}
```

From: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I just saw that no one shows the code to use from a string to an object, so I showd it in a basic form

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0;
do{
    alert(data[i].categoryName);
    i++;
}
while(i<=data.length);
```

As described by Darin Dimitrov, but in a While loop.